# php cleaner method to determine first, second, third or fourth day of month of given date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

There are lots of threads related to this...but most are about getting a future first, second, third or fourth Monday (or Tuesday or Friday..or ...) of a particular month.  Not much on how to determine if a past date is the First or Third day of that month.  Regardless if the day is a Monday, Thursday or any day, I am needing to determine if a given date is the first/second/third/fourth of that particular month.  Then use that info to predict the first/second/third/fourth day of a future month:

I came up with the following, it seems to work just fine, but I am curious to know if there is a better, shorter or cleaner method.

```
// given a past date, 
$day = ("2019-10-13") ;  // happens to be the 2nd Sunday of October ...but how to determine this?

$dow = date('l',strtotime($day)) ;  // returns "Sunday" 
$dom = date('j',strtotime($day)) ;  // returns "13"
$xom = ceil($dom / 7) ;   // returns "2"
$xth = array("","first","second","third","fourth","fifth") ; 
echo $xth[$xom] ;  // echos "second"

// continuing the "sunday" example, get the 2nd Sunday of the current or future month:
$tempDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($xth[$xom]. ' ' .$dow. ' of this month')) ;  // 2020-02-09
$tempDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($xth[$xom]. ' ' .$dow. ' of next month')) ;  // 2020-03-08
$tempDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($xth[$xom]. ' ' .$dow. ' of 2021-08')) ;  // 2021-08-08
```

Is there a cleaner, shorter method to accomplish the same?  I was hoping a simple `date('c`,strtotime($day))`- I know the switch`c`doesn't exist, but if it did maybe return`second sunday` or something like that.

Comment: Well look at the `date('d')` if its 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 then its the first, second ... day of the month

Comment: @RiggsFolly - no, that returns `2019-10-13` simply as the `13th` of that month, its not telling you if its the 2nd Sunday of that month.

Comment: You do know there can be 5 occurrences of a particular weekday in a month?

Comment: @symcbean - yup, thats why my code accounts for "fifth"